# SCJP6 regex issue

Tags: java, regex, scjp

I have issue with following  example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Regex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
        boolean b = false;
        while(b = m.find()) {
            System.out.print(m.start() + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

And the command line:

```
java Regex2 "\d*" ab34ef
```

Can someone explain to me, why the result is: 01234456

regex pattern is d* - it means number one or more but there are more positions that in  args[1],

thanks

Comment: No, `*` means zero or more. `+` means one or more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\d*` matches 0 or more digits. So, it will even match empty string before every character and after the last character. First before index `0`, then before index `1`, and so on.

So, for string `ab34ef`, it matches following groups:

```
Index    Group
  0        ""  (Before a)
  1        ""  (Before b)
  2        34  (Matches more than 0 digits this time)
  4        ""  (Before `e` at index 4)
  5        ""  (Before f)
  6        ""  (At the end, after f)
```

If you use `\\d+`, then you will get just a single group at `34`.

Comment: Does the result have something with position of characters or is result indexes of characters or?

Comment: @Karlo. Result is the index of the character before which the empty string is matched.

Comment: @RohitJain how can it be that the if the `0` index is referring to "Before a" and that the `2` index is at the `34`? if `0` is _before a_, then wouldn't it be the `3` index that is at `34`? Is the scanner at one position and looking to the position to the left of it? Is the scanner position at a but looking at _Before a_?