# Java - Regex pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

I am Relatively inexperienced in regex. I am playing around with various java classes that are used for regex. Below is an example I am trying out -

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.start() + m.group());
        }
    }   
}
```

When I run this I get -

```
0
1
234
4
5
6
```

The m.start() function returns the position of the character the match was found on. The pattern follows a 0 based index.

So here is my interpretation of the output -

```
0   (index = 0 , no matching group)
1   (index = 1 , no matching group)
234 (index = 2 , matching group = 34)
4   (index = 4 , no matching group)
5   (index = 5 , no matching group)
6   (Why does this happen?)
```

Why would m.start() return 6 ? The string is 6 characters long so the last index should be 5. I think I am missing something very basic here. Any pointers or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This has been posted some time ago... `\d*` matches an empty space between symbols and at the start and end of string. And sequences of digits, too. So,your interpretation is wrong, all of those are matches.

Comment: Try testing your code with regex `"^"` and `"$"`

Comment: Your question was closed as duplicate (now updated). Take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/a/18384957/1393766

Comment: You can find more answers with https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ab34ef

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks, I remembered there was identical question, but could not track it down.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right post!